# How to connect Arduino to remote processing server?

Tags: arduino, client-server, wifi, processing, remote-access

I have an arduino which is connected to the RN-XV Wifly module. I want to send data from this to a Processing server which would be in a remote location (can be anywhere in the world and keeps changing).

The RN-XV can only connect to a specific IP address which has to be pre-programmed into it but I will not be able to change that IP every time the processing server moves to a different location.Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by setting up a server on a machine with a static IP address. The RNSV would send data to the server and processing would collect the data from there.